# Where environment variable is defined in ruby in order to be used in jenkins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins

I've in my `env.rb` file this variable

```
ENV['variable_name'] = nil
```

Then, when I try to invoke this variable on `jenkins`, it is not applied.
I've tried with: `string parameters`, `Global variable string parameters`, `Choice parameters`, etc..

have someone faced with problem like this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you using `Capistrano` too? In order to help you, we need more info of what are you trying to achieve with `Jenkins`

Comment: Jenkins doesn't automatically know about the variables you have defined in your project files. Try `require File.join(Dir.home, "<path to env.rb>")
` in an "Execute Ruby Script" of a Build step. You should then be able to access the env variables defined in env.rb in that particular build step.